# Best practice for operating on large amounts of data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, etl

I need to do a lot of processing on a table that has 26+ million rows:

1. Determine correct size of each column based on said column's data
2. Identify and remove duplicate rows.
3. Create a primary key (auto incrementing id)
4. Create a natural key (unique constraint)
5. Add and remove columns

Please list your tips on how to speed this process up and the order in which you would do the list above.

Thanks so much.

UPDATE:  Don't need to worry about concurrent users.  Also, there are no indexes on this table.  This table was loaded from a source file.  When all said and done there will be indexes.

UPDATE: If you use a different list from what I listed, please feel free to mention it.

Based on comments so far and what I have found worked:

1. Create a subset of rows from the 26+ million rows.  I found that 500,000 rows works well.
2. Delete columns that won't be used (if any)
3. Set appropriate datatype lengths for all columns in one scan using max(len())
4. Create a (unique if possible) clustered index on column/columns that will eventually be the natural key.
5. Repeat steps 2-4 on all the rows

Comment: Do you have to worry about concurrent users? What is the current structure of the table including indexes?

Comment: This is something I'm doing for our ETL process.  I will not have to worry about other users.

Comment: What will you be using as the clustered index? What is the typical size and datatypes of the columns you will be deleting?

Comment: @Martin: Typical column datatypes will be varchar.  Typical size < 50.  One column = 300.  I won't know about the indexes other than the ones I listed at this point.

Comment: @subt13 - So currently the table is a heap with no indexes. The clustered index determines the order that the data is stored in. If you are going to have one you would really need to decide what that is going to be upfront. Because if you want to change it you would need to rebuild all your other indexes.

Comment: @Martin - I see.  Then it would make sense to create a clustered index up front, if possible, on the column/columns that will eventually become the natural key (or define uniqueness)?

Comment: Yes unique is good because otherwise SQL Server will just add a uniqueifier anyway, narrow is good because the clustered index key is the row locator and appears in all the non clustered indexes, You would also need to consider the effect of any future inserts to the table - will they cause page splits in the clustered index. Also if you have queries that search on ranges those can be well served by a clustered index as well (though a covering non clustered index can be just as good for this)

Comment: I won't be able to create a unique clustered index up front, but I will be able to create a non-unique clustered index.

Comment: And as a rough guesstimate what proportion of rows would you expect to need to be removed as duplicates - A very small minority?

Comment: Actually I would expect there to be maybe 500,000 - 1,000,000 dups

Comment: And how are you identifying these dupes? Is it that they will have the same value for the columns that you are proposing to use for the clustered index? If so does that mean that if these dupes are eliminated that the clustered index can be unique? Also what version of SQL Server are you on?

Comment: If that is the case I'm wondering if you might just be best off doing your data length check in one scan of the heap then creating a new table with the additional columns you require and minus the ones you don't need and the clustered index in place then loading the data in in clustered index order (the sort operation to get the data in the right order for loading could also be used to eliminate duplicates possibly)

Comment: Yes, same columns that will be the unique index.  SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to remove some columns, you should probably do that first if possible. This will reduce the amount of data you have to read for the other operations.

Bear in mind that when you modify data this may also require modifying indexes that include the data. It is therefore often a good idea to remove the indexes if you plan to make a large number of updates to the table, then add them again afterwards.

Comment: It won't reduce any I/O deleting a column is just a metadata operation in SQL Server.

Comment: @Martin Smith: Step 1: There is no point knowing the correct size of the column if you are going to delete is anyway, so you save time in this step by just deleting this column. Step 2: It will also not need to be read when he compares rows to see if they are duplicates - saving time here too.

Comment: That could equally be achieved by simply not doing these steps for columns that are destined for deletion. But I guess it doesn't make any difference really.

Comment: @Martin Smith: I'd say it's simpler to delete them at the start than having to keep remembering to skip them. If you skip the columns and then delete at the end it just adds unnecessary complication to the process without any benefit.

Comment: Yep I agree actually. I can see no downside to deleting them straight away and it would definitely need to be done before adding the clustered index anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Order: 5, 2, 1, 3, 4

1: No way around it: Select Max(Len(...)) From ...

2: That all depends on what you consider a duplicate.

3: ALTER TABLE in Books Online will tell you how. No way to speed this up, really.

4: See 3.

5: See 3.